# При вводе с клавиатуры, ошибка - ValueError: time data does not match format '%d.%m.%Y'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сразу скажу,что на эту ошибку я нашёл немало вопросов и ответов здесь.
Но не смог получить оттуда нужной для себя информации.
Беру проблемный участок

```
def get_dateorder():            
            dateordd = input('Дата заказа книги(дд-мм-гггг): ')
            dateord = time.strptime(dateordd,"%d.%m.%Y") 
            return dateord
```

**Что хочу получить?**

Ввожу дату с клавитауры, вот так `11121990` и хочу чтобы она у меня выводилась как `11.12.1990`
А в итоге я после ввода получаю

```
ValueError: time data '11121990' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y'
```

**Что я сделал для исправления?**

Перед строкой с `input()` добавлял `str`, так как `strptime()` 1-ым аргументом содержит строку, но ошибка не исчезает.
Ниже представлены 2 варианта исправлений ошибки.

```
def get_dateorder():            
                dateord = str(input('Дата заказа книги(дд-мм-гггг): '))
                return time.strptime(dateord,"%d.%m.%Y")
```

Решил уже добавить `split` чтобы разбить цифры,но ошибка не исчезает

```
def get_dateorder():            
                dateordd = input('Дата заказа книги(дд-мм-гггг): ')
                dateordd = split('.')
                dateord = time.strptime(dateordd,"%d.%m.%Y") 
                return dateord
```

Comment: dateord = time.strptime(dateordd,"%d%m%Y") попробуйте

Comment: Прежде чем исправлять ошибку необходимо понять в чем она заключается... Чтение текста ошибки в этом очень помогает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вводите дату не в том формате.

```py
import time
def get_dateorder():            
                dateordd = input('Дата заказа книги(дд.мм.гггг): ')
                dateord = time.strptime(dateordd,"%d.%m.%Y") 
                return dateord
```

В input - 02.02.2020 (точки ставим с клавиатуры)
Все работает.
Если ввести 02022020 будет ошибка

Answer (score 3):

Вы указали формат даты
`%d.%m.%Y`, а хотите, чтобы оно работало с вводом `11121990` ?
Поменяйте формат на `'%d%m%Y'` и все заработает.

```
def get_dateorder():            
    dateord = input('Дата заказа книги(ддммгггг): ')
    return time.strptime(dateord,"%d%m%Y")
```

Или так:

```
def get_dateorder():          
    return time.strptime(input('Дата заказа книги(ддммгггг): '),"%d%m%Y")
```